# Total Return Swaps

Tags: swap, finance, price

I am trying to understand better Total Return Swaps and how they are priced (I have heard about projection-based and accrual-based models), can any body recommend good material to read (books, websites, exercises,...) or provide any useful information on the topic? Thank you

I made some research but haven't been able to find anything truly enlightening, I expected to get some help.

Comment: Wrong forum @Abelardo

Comment: Options, future and other derivatives by J. Hull contains some discussion on total return swaps. In my 2012 edition it's chapter 24.7 TOTAL RETURN SWAPS. It might be a good starting point, but does not cover pricing in detail. https://quant.stackexchange.com/ is better suited for these type of questions.